SFML project compiles locally but crashes when running CI - error: 'class sf::Rect<float>' has no member named 'getPosition'
I wanted to setup GitLab CI for my project but I get an error 'class sf::Rect' has no member named 'getPosition'. The code compiles on manjaro. Here is the ci file:
image: gcc

before_script:
    - apt-get update --yes
    - apt-get install cmake --yes # Cmake
    - apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev freeglut3-dev mesa-common-dev --yes # OpenGL
    - apt-get install freetype* --yes # freetype
    - apt-get install libogg-dev --yes # OGG
    - apt-get install libvorbis-dev --yes # vorbis
    - apt-get install libflac-dev --yes # flac
    - apt-get install libsfml-dev --yes # SFML
    - apt-get install libudev-dev --yes # UDev
    - apt-get install libopenal1 libopenal-dev --yes # OpenAL
    - apt-get install libx11-dev libxrandr-dev libxcursor-dev --yes # X11

stages:
    - build
    # - test
    # - deliver

BuildCode:
    stage: build
    script:
        - cmake -B build -S .
        - cmake --build build
    artifacts:
        paths:
            - "build/bin/"
        when: on_success
        expire_in: 30 days

The code that fails:
sf::Text text;
text.setFont(font);
text.setString(string);
text.setCharacterSize(kTextSize);
text.setFillColor(color);
text.setPosition(0, 0);
auto rect = text.getGlobalBounds();
auto pos = rect.getPosition();

cmake:
# ...

include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(SFML
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/SFML/SFML.git
    GIT_TAG 2.6.x)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(SFML)

# ...

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE sfml-graphics)

# ...

if (WIN32)
    set(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX)
    set(CMAKE_GNUtoMS TRUE)
    add_custom_command(
        TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}
        COMMENT "Copy OpenAL DLL"
        PRE_BUILD COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${SFML_SOURCE_DIR}/extlibs/bin/$<IF:$<EQUAL:${CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P},8>,x64,x86>/openal32.dll $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:CMakeSFMLProject>
        VERBATIM)
endif ()

install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME})
# ...

Error:
/builds/roman.s.zinin/tp-project/src/interface/visualization.cpp: In member function 'std::pair<long unsigned int, long unsigned int> Visualization::GetTextSize(std::string)':
/builds/roman.s.zinin/tp-project/src/interface/visualization.cpp:70:19: error: 'class sf::Rect<float>' has no member named 'getPosition'
   70 |   auto pos = rect.getPosition();

Expacting the code to compile got error: 'class sf::Rect' has no member named 'getPosition'

So, which SFML you are using, the system one (installed with apt-get install libsfml-dev) or one which is downloaded (with FetchContent_MakeAvailable)? Please, add to the question post full error message: it should include names of files involved into the problem.

It smells like you are using system SFML, which version is 2.5 or older: in that versions sf::Rect class has no method getPosition.

sf::Rect::getPosition was added in 2.6.0 so it is safe to say that your sfml-dev system package is older than the 2.6.0 your CmakeLists pulls in. Remove that package from the installation list. Install the build dependencies with apt-get built-dep libsml-dev if you must.

Tried, got:
$ apt-get built-dep libsfml-dev --yes
E: Invalid operation built-dep
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1


Typo. That should be build-dep

Now:  You must put some 'deb-src' URIs in your sources.list

got You must put some 'deb-src' URIs in your sources.list
